# Stop all Azure Data Factory triggers through CLI

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

I am trying to deploy ARM template through Azure CLI as follows:

```
az deployment group create --name APP-ADF-Template --resource-group <my-resource-group> --template-file ./pipelines/app_arm.json --parameters ./pipelines/app_stage_arm_params.json
```

But getting the error, when any trigger in `Start` state.

```
ERROR: Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 10c0ee19-1452-41ce-8edd-4ecf33499f25. {
  "error": {
    "code": "TriggerEnabledCannotUpdate",
    "message": "Cannot update enabled Trigger; the trigger needs to be disabled first. ",
    "target": null,
    "details": null
  }
}
```

We can stop one by one trigger with the below command.

```
az datafactory trigger stop --factory-name <my-data-factory> --resource-group <my-resource-group> --trigger-name <my-trigger-1>
```

Like this we have more than 10 triggers, it will be difficult to stop one by one. Is there any way to stop all of them at once and start all of them post deployment successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such way to stop all the triggers at one time, in this case, your option is to use a loop.

### Stop all the triggers:

#### For Windows:

```
$names = az datafactory trigger list --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --query "[?properties.runtimeState=='Started'].name" -o tsv --only-show-errors
foreach($name in $names){
    az datafactory trigger stop --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --name $name --only-show-errors
}
```

### For Unix

```
names=`az datafactory trigger list --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --query "[?properties.runtimeState == 'Started'].name" -o tsv --only-show-errors`
                    
for name in ${names[@]}; 
do
    echo "Stopping the trigger : ${name}"
    az datafactory trigger stop --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --name ${name} --only-show-errors
done
```

### After deployment, start all the triggers:

#### For Windows:

```
$names = az datafactory trigger list --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --query "[?properties.runtimeState=='Stopped'].name" -o tsv --only-show-errors
foreach($name in $names){
    az datafactory trigger start --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --name $name --only-show-errors
}
```

### For Unix

```
names=`az datafactory trigger list --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --query "[?properties.runtimeState == 'Stopped'].name" -o tsv --only-show-errors`
                    
for name in ${names[@]}; 
do
    echo "Starting the trigger : ${name}"
    az datafactory trigger start --factory-name "xxx" --resource-group "xxx" --name ${name} --only-show-errors
done
```

Comment: when i use it in windows cli, this error shown '$names' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: how to get $names parameter?